# How do I include the same HTML5 video twice in one page?

Tags: html5-video

I'd like to include an entire HTML5 video in one spot and then a portion of the same video lower on the same page. This abbreviated syntax works for the portion of the video from 1:01 to 3:51.

```
    <video>
    <source src="foo.mp4#t=61,231" type="video/mp4" width="640" height="360"/>
    </video>
```

But the first video shows up normally and the second, shorter video with the same source doesn't seem to get loaded and appears as a small, black video player. But loading the second, shorter video in a second page works normally.

Is is possible to load the full video and then a portion later on the same page?

Thanks.

This works fine in Linux Firefox 22.0 but has the above-described problems in Linux Chromium 28.0

Comment: It works just fine in Firefox 22, what browser do you use?

Comment: @JanTojnar You're right. It **does** work in Firefox. I had been testing in Linux Chromium 28.0.1. In Chromium I can get the second video to appear if either I omit the first _or_ I include the first and start playing it a bit before I try to play the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have the same problem, however I am not even trying to start one video at a different time.  I am just trying to include two of the same big movie twice on a page.  One loads, or the other, but not both.  I tried copying the movie and naming it movie2 and include that in the code.  That works.  Its ugly, so I tried to instead make a symlink rather than copying the movie.  This does work:

ln -s  movie.mp4 movie2.mp4

So as long as you have your code with two different names, they both load.  But on the server side its just one file and a symlink.  This is a workaround, so I would like to find out if there is a bug or something.  My Chrome is 28.0.1500.95

Comment: Many thanks. This symlink workaround works in my Linux Chromium 29.0.1547.32 and Firefox 22.0 (which doesn't need a workaround).

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding query string - for example ?1 -  at the end of the second video src will force browser to download the file again in Chrome

> src="foo.mp4?1"